# Eclipse Plugin: Drop (external) File to editor: dropAccept is not called

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an eclipse plugin which basically is a logviewer.

One of the features should be to drag and drop an external file to the editor component. After recieving that file, the editor is replacing it's content by the content from the file.

I've created the DropTargetAdapter and used `IDragAndDropService.addMergedDropTarget` to add it to editors `StyledText`. My Editor component is inherting from `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor`

During Drag i can see that dragEnter / dragOver is called. But i cannot that see dropAccept or drop is called.

*Big question is why?*

**This is my current Code:**

```
StyledText tw = getSourceViewer().getTextWidget();
int ops = DND.DROP_LINK | DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY;
Transfer[] transfers = { FileTransfer.getInstance() };

DropTargetListener editorListener = new DropTargetAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragEnter detail");
    }

    @Override
    public void dragLeave(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragLeave");
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOperationChanged(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragOperationChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragOver");
    }

    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("drop");
    }

    @Override
    public void dropAccept(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dropAccept");
        //TODO import the file
    }
};
IDragAndDropService dtSvc = getSite().getService(IDragAndDropService.class);
dtSvc.removeMergedDropTarget(tw);
dtSvc.addMergedDropTarget(tw, ops, transfers, editorListener);
```